# Queuing with Multi Tenant Application in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, queue

I am building a multi tenant application where each registered organisation has its own database. The application loads the database configuration dynamically based on the sub domain.

In the application i have an option to send newsletter to all the registered user. I am queuing the all mailing process. But how the queue worker will work with different DBs?

Can anyone guide me on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Specifying The Connection & Queue**
>
> You may also specify which queue connection the worker should utilize. The connection name passed to the work command should correspond to one of the connections defined in your  config/queue.php configuration file:
>
> `php artisan queue:work redis`
>
> You may customize your queue worker even further by only processing particular queues for a given connection. For example, if all of your emails are processed in an emails queue on your redis queue connection, you may issue the following command to start a worker that only processes only that queue:
>
> `php artisan queue:work redis --queue=emails`

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker